# iOS Tab Bar Overlaps Content

Tags: ios, constraints, nib, overlap, tabbar

When working with nibs (not storyboards) and autolayout constraints the tab bar appears to overlap view content by a small arbitrary but constant amount. This occurs with both translucent and opaque nav bars.

iOS 8.0+
xcode 7.2

Answer (score 0):

Check your view's constraints' constant values. If that field displays placeholder text "Standard" try instead giving it a value. Standard in this case apparently means, undefined and potentially unwanted behavior!

Setting the Bottom constraints for all of my child views in the following manner appears to correct the overlapping issue:

```
First Item: ChildView.Bottom
Relation: Equal
Second Item: Superview.Bottom
Constant: 0 (not Standard!)
Priority: 1000
Multiplier: 1
```